# I can't add a classname in React with useEffect or?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, use-effect

I have a Sudoku solver project in react. And I want to style it with react or css. I tried both ways and ended up in a confusion.
The grid component is my main component and I want to style the board like this:

[image]

And here is my simple CSS code

```
    .odd {
      background-color: gray;
    }
```

And my Grid.jsx

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
    import '../App.css';


    export default function Grid() {
        // for every input make sure only one number per an input field can be entered
        const checkInput = (e) => {
            if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
                e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, 1)
            }
        }

        // Driver function for the grid
        const grid = document.querySelectorAll('.grid input')

        useEffect(() => {
            grid.forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('input', checkInput)
            })

            return () => {
                grid.forEach(item => {
                    item.removeEventListener('input', checkInput)
                })
            }
        }, [grid])

        // styling for grid element

        
        useEffect(() => {
            const colorChanger = () => {
                grid.forEach((item, i) => {
                    if (
                        ((i % 9 === 0 || i % 9 === 1 || i % 9 === 2) && i < 21) ||
                        ((i % 9 === 6 || i % 9 === 7 || i % 9 === 8) && i < 27) ||
                        ((i % 9 === 3 || i % 9 === 4 || i % 9 === 5) && (i > 27 && i < 53)) ||
                        ((i % 9 === 0 || i % 9 === 1 || i % 9 === 2) && i > 53) ||
                        ((i % 9 === 6 || i % 9 === 7 || i % 9 === 8) && i > 53)
                    ) {
                        item.classList.add('odd')
                    }
                })
            }
            colorChanger()
        }, [grid])

        return (
            <div className='grid'>
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
                <input type="number" min='1' max='9' />
            </div>
        )
    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So how can I achieve the same result in the picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a more standard React approach, which is to use **Composition**. Basically in your Grid you have *cells*, which is the smallest Component, then you have 9 Squares, which are subunits of 9 cells.

This is a perfect example of composition:

```js
const useEffect = React.useEffect
const useState = React.useState

const cells = Array(9)
  .fill("")
  .map((el, i) => i);
const squares = [...cells]

const Cell = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(1);

  const onChange = (e) => setVal(+e.target.value);
  
  return (
    <input
      className="cell"
      type="number"
      min="1"
      max="9"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={val}
    />
  );
};

const Square = ({ type }) => (
  <div className={`square ${type}`}>
    {cells.map((c) => (
      <Cell key={c} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Grid = () => (
  <div className="grid">
    {squares.map((el, i) => (
      <Square key={el} type={i % 2 !== 0 ? "light" : "dark"} />
    ))}
  </div>
);


ReactDOM.render(<Grid />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
.grid {
width: 396px;
height: 396px;
}

.cell {
width:40px;
height:40px;
padding:0;
background:none;
}

.square {
display:inline-block;
width: 132px;
height: 132px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.dark {
background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will also try it to find out best approach for this type of problems @CesarePolonara

Comment: I fixed the example for a better understanding of composition. Try not to think in the imperative DOM manipulation way when working with React, try to build a flow that goes from static data (arrays of data) to rendering of reusable Components.

Comment: Doing it by 9 * 9 and your modulus trick is solved the issue with background color.Also I have better understanding of reusable components by seing this example. Thank you @Cesare Polonara

Comment: Glad it helped. If you don't want to use the *modulus trick* you can use css pseudoclass `:nth-child(even)` to style only even or odd children.

Answer (score 0):

My first wonder is why are you doing it dynamically if it is something very static by principle.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import "../App.css"

export default function Grid() {
  // for every input make sure only one number per an input field can be entered
  const checkInput = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 1) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, 1)
    }
  }

  // Driver function for the grid
  const grid = document.querySelectorAll(".grid input")

  useEffect(() => {
    grid.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("input", checkInput)
    })

    return () => {
      grid.forEach((item) => {
        item.removeEventListener("input", checkInput)
      })
    }
  }, [grid])

  // styling for grid element

  const sudoku = [
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  ]

  var inputs = []
  const iterate = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

  iterate.forEach((i) =>
    iterate.forEach((j) =>
      inputs.append(
        <input
          type="number"
          className={sudoku[i][j] === 1 ? "odd" : ""}
          min="1"
          max="9"
        />
      )
    )
  )

  return <div className="grid">{inputs}</div>
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong . replaced append with push and added a key for each item but result is still not desired   `      inputs.push(
        <input
            key={`${i}${j}`}
          type="number"
          className={sudoku[i][j] === 1 ? "odd" : ""}
          min="1"
          max="9"
        />
      )
    })
  })

Comment: Your intent is perfectly valid and accepted but the code you provided has numerous mistakes in it. Could you correct your code? You have a +1 from me in advance when you do.

Comment: I added a second screenShot of the App in wide angle @catgirlkelly

Comment: `.odd {
  background-color:  gray !important;
}`                                                         added !important and now it is working ? Thanks to @catgirlkelly  @Gabriel Pellegrino

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to test it right now... I made some changes, I hope that they solve the problems it had...

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is like this

```js
  const inputs = [];

  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].forEach((i) => {
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].forEach((j) => {
      inputs.push(
        <input
          key={`${i}${j}`}
          type="number"
          className={sudoku[i][j] === 1 ? "odd" : ""}
          min="1"
          max="9"
        />
      )
    })
  })
  return <div className="grid">{inputs}</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And when I insept it, classname is appended but I can't see the change off an background-color
[image]